# getting http session cookies in spring-ws soap web service client

Tags: web-services, cookies, soap, http-headers, spring-ws

I have a SOAP web service client written with Spring-WS. In response to a logon request, the web service I connect to returns a session cookie in the HTTP response header with a token in it. Each subsequent call to the service requires that cookie with the token. How can I get the session cookie from the response and then add it to the HTTP header on subsequent calls to the service?

To summarize what I'm asking, how do you extract and inject cookies with Spring-WS.

Here is a snippet of code similar to what I am using to call into the web service:

```
    MySessionLogon api = new MySessionLogon();
    api.setUsername(username);
    api.setPassword(password);

    MySessionLogonResponse response = (MySessionLogonResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(
                    "http://myserver/soapservice.asmx",
                    api,
                    new SoapActionCallback("http://www.myserver.com/MySession_Logon"));

    return response;
```

I have searched the internet and read a lot of things that seem close to what I need, but I haven't seen a good way to get the value of the cookies I need to use. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [WebServiceMessageExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceMessageExtractor.html)  ?

You could do the following

```
MySessionLogonResponse response = (MySessionLogonResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .sendAndReceive(
                    "http://myserver/soapservice.asmx",
                    api,
                    new SoapActionCallback("http://www.myserver.com/MySession_Logon"),
new WebServiceMessageExtractor<ResponseAndHeader>() {
    public ResponseAndHeader extractData(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
    HttpComponentsConnection con = (HttpComponentsConnection) context.getConnection();
    httpResponse httpResponse = con.getHttpResponse();
    //use the method getHeaders from to retrieve the data you want    
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response VirtualTroll. Just a note, marshalSendAndReceive doesn't accept four parameters as shown in your response. I'm guessing I would need to use one of the other SendAndReceive methods provided by WebServiceTemplate.

Comment: Updated my answer. Were you able to solve your problem using the solution ?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, but I solved my problem by going a different route. I implemented a solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189129/spring-ws-client-set-cookie-for-authentication with valuable input from: <https://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/jax-ws-client-consuming-the-jax-ws-webservice> and <http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2008/11/consuming-web-services-with-spring.html> among others. Thanks again for your input even though I didn't go that way. @VirtualTroll